# Откуда функция, созданная внутри метода знает о классе, в котором она создана?

Tags: python, область-видимости, декоратор

Задача: написать декоратор, который будет логировать каждый вызов функции.

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(self.count + 1) + '\n')
            self.count += 1
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped


logger = Logger('log.txt')

@logger
def completely_useless_function():
    pass
```

Задача решена, код работает, но возник вопрос. Откуда `completely_useless_function` знает о `self.filename`? Ведь когда вызывается декоратор (`@logger`) происходит ничто иное как: `completely_useless_function = logger(completely_useless_function)`. После этого `completely_useless_function` становится внутренней функцией `wrapped`. Значит, всегда когда я делаю вызов `completely_useless_function()`, я вызываю `wrapped()`. Но `wrapped` не должен знать о `self.filename` т.к. мы не передаём внутрь функции параметр `self`... Почему не возникает ошибки при обращении к полям `self.filename`, `self.count`? Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать про механизм того, как происходит объявление функции `wrapped`, и какая у неё связь с классом `Logger`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция, созданная внутри метода класса, ничего о классе не знает.
Но в Вашем случае она знает того, кто знает =).

Это аргумент `self`. Он передаётся в метод `__call__` и `wrapped` может получить к нему доступ, поискав в объемлющей области видимости.

Происходит это примерно так:

- Имя `self` есть в локальной области видимости? Нет! Значит поищу выше.
- Выше функция, в ней есть имя `self`? Есть! Отлично, обращаюсь к нему.

Если бы на этом этапе имя `self` так и не нашлось бы, то функция продолжила бы искать выше, например, в глобальной области видимости.

Функция `completely_useless_function` тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!